# Invalid file paths from subfolders

Tags: php, html, path

I have a problem when using the require/include statement in PHP. I have a file with a lot of code that is being used on several pages since I want to reuse that code. My problem is that I want to include this code on pages that are in different folders than other files I want to include. That means all images and other paths in the file I want to reuse will get invalid since I include them from different destinations on the server.
Is there a better way or a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use absolute paths, or a base path hardcoded in a config file somewhere that all other pages refer to.

Comment: You should define a constant with server root absolute path. Then you will be able to reference your media files regardless of what php file you're using right now.

Comment: Is the problem the paths in the html document or the paths for the php includes?

Comment: the problem is the paths in the html document :) and good idea guys, I will try and search for it.

Comment: If you use relative paths to the document root `/whatever/image.png` you should be just fine.

Comment: oooh... I never even thought of that. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score -1, accepted):

give `URI` to  Any `include or require` By itself:

Sample:

index.php in `root` folder:

```
<?php
include('Control/file.php');
?>
```

---

iran.php in `root>>Control` folder:

```
<?php
include('/../Model/file.php');
?>
```

---

iran.php in `root>>Model` folder:

```
<?php
  echo "Hellow";
?>
```

Comment: Ah nice, thanks a lot. However, PeeHaa had a good solution that I didn't think of. Thanks again!